# Why would this functional test be failing?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, functional-testing

My haml :

```
- for status in current_account.job_statuses.active
  = link_to status.name, '#', :class => params[:job_status_id].to_i == status.id ? "current status block" : "status block", :rel => status.id
```

My html :

```
<a rel="1" class="status block" href="#">in progress</a>
<a rel="2" class="status block" href="#">in progress</a>
<a rel="3" class="status block" href="#">in progress</a>
<a rel="4" class="status block" href="#">in progress</a>
```

My Test :

```
test 'index - job_status: set' do
  job_status = @account.job_statuses.create! :name => 'foo'
  job_status.reload

  @job.update_attribute :job_status_id, job_status.id
  @job.reload

  get :index, :job_status_id => job_status.id.to_s
  assert_response :success
  assert_template 'jobs/index'

  jobs = assigns(:jobs)

  assert jobs.include?(@job)
  assert_select 'div.status[rel=?]', job_status.id
end
```

But I get this failure :

```
  3) Failure:
test_index_-_job_status:_set(NewJobsControllerTest)
    [test/functional/new_jobs_controller_test.rb:127:in `block in <class:NewJobsControllerTest>'
     test/test_helper.rb:221:in `run'
     test/test_helper.rb:221:in `run']:
Expected at least 1 element matching "div.status[rel='16']", found 0.
<false> is not true.
```

Is this for an obvious dumb reason? I apologize if it is.. I can't figure it out.

Comment: How's that HTML generated?  Can you post the ERB snippet, if there is one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh.  It's always the little things we never think to check...  After staring uselessly at that HAML I asked for for five minutes it hit me:

**Those ain't `DIV`s.  Those are `A`s.**

Cheers!